# reply all message page facebook with sdk python

Tags: facebook, sdk

conv = pagefacebook.get_object("me/conversations")
msg = pagefacebook.get_object(conv["data"][0]["id"] + "/messages")
print(conv)

```
for el in msg["data"]:
    content = pagefacebook.get_object(el["id"])  # adding the field request
    print(content["id"])

    args = {"fields": "message"}
    msgtext = pagefacebook.get_object("/" + content["id"], **args)
    print(msgtext)

    callSendAPI("106045308371301", "this is aloha")
    pagefacebook.put_object("106045308371301", "messages", message="hello, world")
    break
```

Comment: so what is your question? any error message?

Comment: I can't send a message to the followers of my page with this code
I am a beginner

Comment: again, do you get any error message?

Comment: no, I have no error, but the message is not sent to me

Comment: sorry here is the error : {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter recipient is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Aiak2u8q4CE75AaoHqy5IAJ"}}

Comment: well, add the parameter then :)